# Making a dynamic method Country and Population using CodeDOM

Tags: c#, codedom

Can someone help me and tell me what am I doing wrong with this code. The Output is supposed to look like this on a file:

```
class Country {
        public string Name {get; set;}
        public int Population {get; set;}
       
        public Country(string name, int population){
                Name = name;
                Population = population;
        }
        public string GetCountryInfo(){
                return "Country" + Name + " has the population of " + Population + ".";
        }
}
```

This is how my code looks like:

```
namespace Assignment_Refleksija_2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Creating Assembly
            CodeCompileUnit countryAssembly = new CodeCompileUnit();

            // Creating Namesapce
            CodeNamespace countryNamespace = new CodeNamespace("RefleksijaCountry");

            // Importing libraries
            countryNamespace.Imports.Add(new CodeNamespaceImport("System"));

            //Creating Class Country
            CodeTypeDeclaration countryClass = new CodeTypeDeclaration();
            countryClass.Name = "Country";
            countryClass.IsClass = true;
            countryClass.Attributes = MemberAttributes.Public;

            //Importing Class Country
            countryNamespace.Types.Add(countryClass);

            //Creating Property Name
            CodeMemberProperty propertyName = new CodeMemberProperty();
            propertyName.Name = "Name";
            propertyName.Type = new CodeTypeReference(typeof(System.String));
            propertyName.Attributes = MemberAttributes.Public;
            CodeSnippetExpression getSnippetName = new CodeSnippetExpression("return Name");
            CodeSnippetExpression setSnippetName = new CodeSnippetExpression("Name = value");
            propertyName.GetStatements.Add(getSnippetName);
            propertyName.SetStatements.Add(setSnippetName);

            //Creating Property Population
            CodeMemberProperty propertyPopulation = new CodeMemberProperty();
            propertyName.Name = "Name";
            propertyName.Type = new CodeTypeReference(typeof(System.Int32));
            propertyName.Attributes = MemberAttributes.Public;
            CodeSnippetExpression getSnippetPopulation = new CodeSnippetExpression("return Population");
            CodeSnippetExpression setSnippetPopulation = new CodeSnippetExpression("Population = value");
            propertyName.GetStatements.Add(getSnippetPopulation);
            propertyName.SetStatements.Add(setSnippetPopulation);

            //Creating Country Method
            CodeMemberMethod methodCountry = new CodeMemberMethod();
            methodCountry.Name = "Country";
            CodeParameterDeclarationExpression name = new CodeParameterDeclarationExpression(typeof(string), "name");
            CodeParameterDeclarationExpression population = new CodeParameterDeclarationExpression(typeof(int), "population");
            methodCountry.Attributes = MemberAttributes.Public | MemberAttributes.Final;
            CodeSnippetExpression snippetname = new CodeSnippetExpression("Name = name");
            CodeSnippetExpression snippetpopulation = new CodeSnippetExpression("Population = population");
            CodeExpressionStatement cse1 = new CodeExpressionStatement(snippetname);
            CodeExpressionStatement cse2 = new CodeExpressionStatement(snippetpopulation);
            methodCountry.Statements.Add(cse1);
            methodCountry.Statements.Add(cse2);

            //Creating GetCountryInfo Method
            CodeMemberMethod methodGetCountryInfo = new CodeMemberMethod();
            methodCountry.Name = "GetCountryInfo";
            CodeTypeReference returnTypeString = new CodeTypeReference(typeof(System.String));
            methodGetCountryInfo.ReturnType = returnTypeString;
            methodCountry.Attributes = MemberAttributes.Public;
            CodeSnippetExpression snippetone = new CodeSnippetExpression("return Name + Population");

            //Create File
            GenerateCSharpCode(countryAssembly, "HelloWorld");
        }
```

And this is how the file generator look like

```
public static string GenerateCSharpCode(CodeCompileUnit compileunit, string fileName)
        {

            CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();

            string sourceFile;
            if (fileName.Equals(""))
            {
                sourceFile = "Untitled.cs";
            }
            else
            {
                sourceFile = fileName + ".cs";
            }

            // Create a TextWriter to a StreamWriter to the output file.
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(sourceFile, false))
            {
                IndentedTextWriter tw = new IndentedTextWriter(sw, "    ");

                // Generate source code using the code provider.
                provider.GenerateCodeFromCompileUnit(compileunit, tw,
                    new CodeGeneratorOptions());

                // Close the output file.
                tw.Close();
            }

            return sourceFile;
        }
```

I tried many times to fix it but the file output just brings out an empty page. I don't know if the order is incorrect or if I made a syntax error or wrong input order. I'm new at dynamic programming so I don't know how to do much of this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is probably with buffering of your writers at the end.

Both StreamWriter and IndentedTextWriter are allowed to buffer the things they're supposed to be writing - instead of immediately passing on each character that's fed into them, they accumulate them temporarily in memory and only actually write when either the buffer is full or they're told to 'flush'.

And... flushing happens in two ways: 1) they're explicitly told to do it via the `Flush()` method or 2) they're nicely disposed (eg via a `using` block). Normally you don't have to think about any of this because the `using` block quietly flushes the buffers for you.

...and so...

I notice that `IndentedTextWriter` isn't part of a `using` block, which means it isn't being disposed nicely. I bet you it's filling up its buffer and not actually writing anything to the underlying StreamWriter before it's abruptly closed manually.

The solution? Something like this (hopefully!):

```cs
using (var sw = new StreamWriter(sourceFile, false))
using (var tw = new IndentedTextWriter(...))
{
    provider.GenerateCodeFromCompileUnit(compileunit, tw,
                    new CodeGeneratorOptions());
    
    //no explicit close needed

} //tw implicitly disposed here (ie flushed + closed)
```